# Passing parameters to a view in Django

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-views, parameter-passing

In my `urls.py` I have set `handler404` to `CustomErrorView`. `CustomErrorView` is a generic view which generates a template for an error based on the error message and error code that it receives.

Since the `handler404` is only raised in the case of a 404 error, how can I send the `errorcode = 404` kwarg to `CustomErrorView` whenever it is raised?

Already tried-

- `handler404 = CustomErrorView(errorcode = 404)`

   This causes an "Expected one positional argument, none given error."

  `handler404 = CustomErrorView(request, errorcode = 404)` 
  This causes a NameError (`Name 'request' is not defined`)

My urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.contrib import admin
from blog_user.views import home, create_error_view

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^$', home),
    url(r'^', include('user_manager.urls')),
    ]

handler404 = create_error_view(error = 404)
handler500 = create_error_view(error = 500)
```

My views.py (after using the modifications recommended by @knbk) :

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseNotFound

def create_error_view(error = 404, mybad = False):
    def custom_error_view(request, error, mybad):
        ''' Returns a generic error page. Not completed yet. error code and messages are supposed to be modular so that it can be used anywhere for any error in the page.'''
        content = "Incorrect url"
        context= {
            'error': error,
            'content':content,
            'mybad':mybad
        }
        response = render(request, 'error.html', context=context, status=error)
        return HttpResponse(response)
    return custom_error_view
```

Comment: In case any of my code is required to solve the problem, please ask.

Comment: Is `CustomErrorView` a class-based view subclassing Django's `View`?

Comment: @knbk No.. it is a function-based (normal) view.

Comment: post your view with urls.py

Answer (score 1):

You can use a function closure to create the view function:

```
def create_error_view(error_code):
    def custom_error_view(request, *args, **kwargs):
        # You can access error_code here
    return custom_error_view
```

Then just call `create_error_view` to set the handler:

```
handler404 = create_error_view(error_code=404)
```

Or you can use `functools.partial()`, which basically does the same:

```
from functools import partial

handler404 = partial(custom_error_view, error_code=404)
```

Comment: Now I get some middleware errors: `'function' object has no attribute 'get'`

Comment: @PrithvishBaidya Traceback?

Comment: Can't get a traceback because error pages are only displayed when `DEBUG = False`